How do I create this facet_grid() plot from the Bayes Rules! textbook using my own data?
I have simulated some data, and I would like to visualize it like the data plotted in this picture:

The picture is from this page of this textbook: https://www.bayesrulesbook.com/chapter-4#striking-a-balance-between-the-prior-data
I have data that I would like to use in a similar plot, but I cannot figure out how the authors created this image. The differing sample sizes of the simulations they used are what is stumping me. I would simply create a data frame, but the differing sample sizes are throwing me off because vectors of different lengths cannot be combined into the same data frame.
I used the bayesplot_grid function from the bayesplot package in my attempt to create a similar image, but every plot has a separate x and y axis title.

p1 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 215, sd = 0.5, sigma = 0.5, y_bar = 215, n = 10)
p2 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 215, sd = 0.5, sigma = 1, y_bar = 220, n = 100)
p3 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 215, sd = 0.5, sigma = 1.5, y_bar = 225, n = 1000)
p4 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 220, sd = 1, sigma = 0.5, y_bar = 215, n = 10)
p5 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 220, sd = 1, sigma = 1, y_bar = 220, n = 100)
p6 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 220, sd = 1, sigma = 1.5, y_bar = 225, n = 1000)
p7 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 225, sd = 1.5, sigma = 0.5, y_bar = 215, n = 10)
p8 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 225, sd = 1.5, sigma = 1, y_bar = 220, n = 100)
p9 = plot_normal_normal(mean = 225, sd = 1.5, sigma = 1.5, y_bar = 225, n = 1000)
bayesplot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, legends = FALSE)

